# Microphone volume very low

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I've installed Ubuntu, but the microphone volume level is very low (using Skype, for example).

It looks like the problem is only on the Settings page, because if I open "Pulse Audio Meter", it looks like it's working fine.

Could you check my attached screenshot?

[image: volume settings]

Comment: @agha rehan abbas Please take care not to lose the original meaning of the post when editing. Microphone is an input not an output.

Comment: @ElderGeek i apologize for that and i will make sure that i will be keen on editing any other future posts and a special thanks for showing me my mistake

Answer (score 18):

Your alsamixer settings show that the Mic is muted.

Open a terminal and issue the command: `alsamixer`

Use the arrow keys to highlight "Mic" which will be red.

Tap the M key and use the up and down arrow keys to adjust. (I would start at the midway point and adjust until I got the results I wanted).

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind also is to make sure the column under `Capture` is not muted; to verify press `<F5>` to see it. In my case it was muted, so i just have to adjust that column