# Low microphone volume on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, volume-control

I am having an issue when using external mic, either with bluetooth, jack cable or USB cable: the input volume is very low, I can barely hear my voice.

It seems this has been a problem in the past ([Microphone volume very low](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498139/microphone-volume-very-low), [My microphone volume is very low](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168902/my-microphone-volume-is-very-low)) but some of the answers are very old. It seems the problem is still not fixed in 20.04? Is it fixed in more recent versions?

So, in brief, what should I do to have a higher input volume?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the system main menu (i.e., Whisker Menu), find your PulseAudio "Volume Control" application (or find it in "System Settings"/"Sound") then select "Input Devices". Under "Built-in Audio Devices" and select a port: "Internal Microphone" (or "External" if listed) and adjust the volume slider.